# Problem with Codelite and MinGw64 (cant get them to work)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw-w64, codelite

I have installed mingw64 and added it as a variable in the control panel, and when I tested it in the cmd (using `g++ --version`) and it work fine. Then I installed codelite and created a workspace (making sure I selected mingw64 as the compiler). I created a "hello" program and ran it, but got an error. I tried reinstalling both mingw64 and codelite but it does not change a thing.

This is the error I get:

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C ""C:/Program
> Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
> -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile"
>
> 'C:\Users\A' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> The system cannot find the path specified. mingw32-make.exe: ***
> [Makefile:4: All] Error 1
> ====0 errors, 0 warnings====

This is test code in case the problem is there:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello testing";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your username on this machine contain spaces?

Comment: Share where you installed MinGW in your machine, how did you add it to the environment variables and a scrrenshot of codelite where you think identified the MinGW installation

Comment: Paddy your advice worked thanks! Had no idea having spaces is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! For anyone in the future with the problem, my problem was that there was a space in my username, guess mingw does not like that haha. Just change user name rcreate a new user :)